# AttributeError: 'Python' object has no attribute 'control'

Tags: python, pygame

I'm a beginner at Python and this project is my first project.
I made a code that moves snakes, and when I play the game and press the direction key, the game stops and this error occurs.
This Error is last error in my projcet.
I don't understand this error.
What should I do?

```
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_UP:
                python.control(UP)
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                python.control(DOWN)
            elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                python.control(LEFT)
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                python.control(RIGHT)
```

Comment: What is `python`? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Maybe you are intending to write pygame.control instead of python?

Comment: Please ensure that you are using the correct libraries. I don't think you intend to use 'python'.

Comment: What is `python`? Is it a module, class or object? Is the function or method `control` defined?

Comment: oh... i'm sorry, guys

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have defined a function named 'control' or see if you are referring the right object name.